# add already tracked file to index

Tags: libgit2

in git it would be

```
1. create file a.txt
2. commit file a.txt
3. a.txt is tracked
```

I can do that in libgit2 easily. 
However, If I modify a.txt and wanted to add it to index I will do
`git add a.txt`

Unfortunately I cannot emulate that with libgit2. I have tried virtually everything the internet offered yet nothing worked. So I feel I miss something basic here. Note that I can add new files that aren't tracked to index with no problem, only I cannot find the way to add them.

Here is the code that I have.

```
void add_file(char *file)
{
    git_index *index;
    int error;
    const git_index_entry *entry;
    git_index_entry new_entry;

    error = git_repository_index(&index, m_repo);
    entry = git_index_get_bypath(index,file, 0);
    if(entry)
    {
        memcpy(&new_entry, entry, sizeof(git_index_entry));
        new_entry.path = file;
        new_entry.mode = GIT_FILEMODE_BLOB;
        error = git_index_add(index, &entry);
    }
    else
        error = git_index_add_bypath(index, file);

    error = git_index_write(index);
    git_index_free(index);
}
```

**EDIT:**

After Ed's post I update my code but it is still adding only new files that aren't tracked.

```
git_index *index;
git_oid tree;
int error;

error = git_repository_index(&index, m_repo);
error = git_index_add_bypath(index, file);
error = git_index_write(index);
error = git_index_write_tree(&tree, index);

git_index_free(index);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `git_index_get_bypath` gives you the index entry as it exists currently.  You're then `memcpy`ing the `entry` that is in the index and `git_index_add`ing it right back.  You're not actually *changing* the entry at all.

(That is, unless the index entry is currently executable.  In which case you are removing the execute bit by setting the `mode` to `GIT_FILEMODE_BLOB`.)

You probably don't want to use `git_index_add` here, as that actually edits the low-level contents of the index directly.  You would need to add the file to the object database and then update the index with the resultant OID.

If the file is changed on disk, then just run `git_index_add_bypath` and let libgit2 update the index with the contents as they exist on disk.

Comment: can you explain a bit in terms of API call for this: 

"You would need to add the file to the object database and then update the index with the resultant OID"

which API methods should I call exactly?

Comment: Never mind, I found it. It is `git_index_write_tree`.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you said. Can you explain  the third paragraph may be with an example (not necessarily full working). I thought I understood but I think I completely misunderstood. See updated post

Comment: so after reading I got to add it added by `git_blob_create_fromworkdir` but I still cannot figure out how to `update the index with the resultant OID`. Can you please hep me the API that does it? I didn't imagine that this task would be the most difficult of all.

Comment: What you posted should definitely work.  What does the contents of the index look like before and after?  You can use `git ls-files --stage` to see.

Comment: I ran git fsck and there errors about dangling stuffs. I think the repo might be messed up. I will delete and start a fresh. I was reading git_index_add_all and git_index_update_all can be filtered with filespec. Would you recommend that route?

I will test and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: It happened that the repository was corrupted at some point. wiping it out and re-cloning worked fine. Thank you!